# A short story about a man who unexpectedly received in the post a machine which can draw pictures alone. found in an anthology audiobook

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

A short story about a man who unexpectedly received several packets in the post which finally result to build a somehow 'printer' which  discover, surprisingly, that can draw fantastic pictures 'alone' (and able to choose from different subjects).

He starts to making a lot of money with the pictures and... well I don't remember much more.

Found in an sci-fi short stories anthology audiobook, 15 or so years ago.

Comment: fun fact: this was recently invented, for real.

Answer (score 17):

This is probably "[Thing of Beauty](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46037)" by Damon Knight.

Due to a timeslip or parallel-universe-slip, the protagonist receives a futuristic drawing machine as a delivery. It enables him to become a successful artist by selling the drawings it creates.

The twist ending is that, in his attempts to figure out the controls, he has set the machine to delete the pictures from its memory after it draws them, so when it runs out of pictures, his career is over.

The story can be read in its original Galaxy publication using this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQOeNHHPQq7b6MvxAn9-1uAJmtofPpKT/view) from the Luminist Archives.

Comment: Bullseye!  Thank you and thank you.
I didn't expect to find it. And as already commented, now the story from sci-fi realm jumps into the real world (and the money involved seems also real)  Bravo To D. Knight